# Is it an example of bilinear pairing?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Consider a bilinear pairing $e: G_1 \times G_2 \rightarrow G_T$. Let's assume, $G_1 = G_2 = G_T = (\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$, i.e. additive group of integer modulo $n$ and $e(x,y) = xy$ mod $n$. Isn't it an example of bilinear map?

$G_1 = G_2 = G_T = (\mathbb{Z}_n,\ast)$, i.e. multiplicative group of integer modulo $n$ and $e(x,y) = y^x$ mod $n$, is it still a bilinear map?

Can there be other bilinear map defined over $\mathbb{Z}_n$?

**EDIT**:

---

Actually all my question were to understand [Groth-Sahai proof system](https://eprint.iacr.org/2007/155). Here, they have recast the general equation to fit the form of a quadratic equation. (See teh highlighted part below). But, how can they remark that all maps with $f(x,y) = xy$ mod $n$ will satisfy properties of bilinear pairing?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your secondxample  assume you mean $\mathbb Z_n^\times$, i.e., the $\phi(n)$ element gorup of invertible elements mod $n$. Note that $y^x\pmod n$ makes little sense as in general we do not have $y^{x+n}\equiv y^n\pmod n$. Also, while w have $(y_1y_2)^x\equiv y_1^x\cdot y_2^x$, we do not have $y^{x_1x_2}\equiv y^{x_1}y^{x_2}$. You may want to look at $(\mathbb Z_n^\times,\cdot)\times (\mathbb Z_{\phi(n)},+)\to (\mathbb Z_n^\times,\cdot)$ instead.

For your second question, $(\mathbb Z_n,+)\times (\mathbb Z_n,+)\to (\mathbb Z_n,+)$, $(x,y)\mapsto cxy$ is bilinear for eny  fixed $c\in\mathbb Z_n$

Comment: Did I correctly identify first one to be a bilinear map?

Comment: Also, is $\phi(n)$ Euler's totient function?

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock Yes (cf. my last statement with $c=1$) and Yes

Comment: I have edited the original question, can you please have a look?